# Rails 5 Model.where(user_id) - Two levels up

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Terribly worded, but I'm confusing it.

I have a `User` model who `has_many Clients` and `has_many statements, through: :clients` and then `statements` which `belongs_to clients` and `belongs to user`

In Console I can do all the queries I want. `User.statements` `User.client.first.statements` etc - What I'm struggling on is `Controller restrictions`

For now it's simple - A user should only be able to see `Clients` and `Statements` in which they own.

For Clients I did
**Client Controller**

```
def index
    @clients = Client.where(user_id: current_user.id)
end
```

Which seems to work perfectly. Client has a field for user_id

I'm kind of stuck on how to emulate this for Statements. Statements do -not- have a user_id field. I'm not quite sure I want them too since in the very-soon-future I want clients to `belongs_to_many` :users and Statements to not be bound.

**Statement Controller**

```
  def index
    @clients = Client.where(user_id: current_user.id)
    @statements = Statement.where(params[:client_id])
  end
```

I'm just genuinely not sure what to put - I know the `params[:client_id]` doesn't make sense, but what is the proper way to fulfill this? Am I going about it an unsecure way?

**Client Model**

```
class Client < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :statements
    has_many :client_notes, inverse_of: :client
    belongs_to :user
    validates :name, presence: true
    validates :status, presence: true
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :client_notes, reject_if: :all_blank, allow_destroy: true
end
```

**Statement Model**

```
class Statement < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :client
    belongs_to :user
    validates :name, presence: true
    validates :statement_type, presence: true
    validates :client_id, presence: true
    validates :start_date, presence: true
    validates :end_date, presence: true
end
```

**User Model**

```
class User < ApplicationRecord

  has_many :clients
  has_many :statements, through: :clients
end
```

Based on the reply provided below I am using

```
  def index
    if params[:client][:user_id] == @current_user.id
      @clients = Client.includes(:statements).where(user_id: params[:client][:user_id])
      @statements = @clients.statements
    else
      return 'error'
    end
  end
```

Unsure if this logic is proper

Comment: Can you add your models to see their relationships?

Comment: @SebastiánPalma Done.

Comment: Why the down-vote?

Answer (score 2):

Use [includes](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/includes) to avoid [N+1] queries.

And regarding *"A user should only be able to see Clients and Statements in which they own"*.

```
if params[:client][:user_id] == @current_user.id
  @clients = Client.includes(:statements).where(user_id: params[:client][:user_id])
  # do more
else
  # Type your error message
end
```

Additionally, you might need to use [strong params](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/StrongParameters.html) and [scope](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Scoping/Named/ClassMethods.html).

Comment: Is it `@current_user` or `current_user`?

Comment: depends on your use, @current_user is instance variable, current_user is local variable and not accessible outside its scope

Comment: I guess is the Devise `current_user`, that's why.

Comment: @BigB I appreciate the response. I haven't used Includes before, so I will review. I am using strong params. I am getting a 
`undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass` response on the if params[] but I'm trying to figure out what it's doing so I can troubleshoot it.

As a quick test I put something like (I put it in the original post for cleanliness)

Comment: answer includes the link to official api dock, I can't comment unless you specify, can you update what is your hash params and where are you getting error

Comment: @BigB Apologies, but I don't understand the ask about the hash params. Nothing is being passed to the controller (This would be the index function). I'm currently testing `@statements = current_user.statements` but I don't believe `current_user` is properly being passed, which might be the issue I had with your method

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do it is using includes:

```
@clients = Client.where(user_id: current_user.id)
@statements = Statement.includes(clients: :users}).where('users.id = ?', current_user.id)
```

You can take a look in here: https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/includes

Comment: This query logic confuses me. The client_id shouldn't be what we compare to user_id. They're not the same.
User has Clients who have Statements. Or is it doing something I'm unaware of?

Comment: Sorry is user_id instead client_id. I edit the answer.

Comment: Thanks, but still having an issue. 
`undefined method `statements' for #<Client::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x007f76fa89d758>`
On your second line

Comment: You need to add multiple nested includes. I think this will work. I edit answer

Answer (score 0):

In this case, thanks to the reminder that `current_user` is a helper from Devise, and the relational structure I showed, it was actually just as simple as

```
def index
    @statements = current_user.statements
end
```

resolved my issue.

Due to the [[N+1] Queries issue](https://secure.phabricator.com/book/phabcontrib/article/n_plus_one/) that @BigB has brought to my attention, while this method works, I wouldn't suggest it for a sizable transaction.

Comment: understand this, you need "#includes" if you want the clients table records along with statements table records keeping away [N+1] queries issue as you had previously described your question, current_user in context of your code is devise helper.

Comment: @BigB Thanks for the insight. I actually Googled the term to understand. I wasn't aware that's how it functioned. I appreciate the mention. I will try to figure out using your method instead.